# extract from database if key contatin string in SQL 2008using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with two columns - the key contains the image name, like love_me.jpg.  The second column contains the link for this image (IE: http:\...\love_me.jpg).

I want a query that will extract the link if I search using only "love".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL command is pretty basic.

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT imagelink FROM Dataimages where (imagename like '%" + keywords + "%')"
```

As for the C# part, that will depend a lot on where the data is located, what type of database it's in and what you want to do with the data once you've obtained it.

Comment: is this syntax true 
string sqlQuery = "SELECT imagelink FROM Dataimages where (imagename like'" +"%"+keywords+"%" + "')"; where keywords is variable string ?

Comment: Modified the answer to include answer to your comment.